# Pass uploaded file as argument to .bat file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, file-upload

I need to run a .bat file in my website that scans files and generate the results to the user.

Following is the steps that are required to accomplish the task: 
1. The user will upload a .zip file by using the FileUpload tool.
2. The uploaded file will be passed as one of the .bat file arguments in order to scan it.
3. The .bat file will scan the .zip file and then generate the output (new files will be added to the shared folder).

I was able to complete step #1 by uploading the file to a shared location. Then I passed the path of the newly uploaded file to the .bat file but no results are shown.

I checked the permissions on the server and granted the website the required access.
Also, I installed the latest java version on the server but with no luck.

The code works perfectly on my local machine but whenever I uploaded to the server it didn't work.

```
string scanFile = @"\\...path..";
string outputLocation = @"\\...path..";
string args = "--project" +name.Text+ "--scan" +scanFile+ "--out" +outputLocation;

//The method that start the process and run .bat file
protected void startP (string path, string args)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments= args;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute= false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow= true;
    p.StartInfo.EnableRaisingEvents= true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaiteForExit();

    if(p.HasExited)
    {
        p.Close();
        // then calling other methods
    }
}
```

Would you please help me figure out what is the problem? specially that the same exact code run and give the desired output on my local machine but not when I run it through the server !

NOTE: 
* The .bat file is uploaded on the server

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to run the scan tool directly with parameters via the `p` object rather than wrapping a batch file around it?

Comment: May you please help with the code?

Comment: Can you add the .bat code to your question? I asked because then we can see how your scanner is invoked and create some C# start code - eliminating the need to create a batch file at all.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that we do not usually give Webservers the kinds of rights needed for this. Webservers are always on, so they are vulnerable to hacking 24/7. As a result they are commonly run under a seperate user that just has read rights to the servers Programm and the webpages content diretory - not a single right bit more.

Execution and write rights? People will scratch their head why you would even ask for that and then propably keep away from your programm. If you give a webserver Write rights you end up with a hacker adding a script that redirects everyone reaching your page via google to a pornographic page (real life example).

The thing is also that this this should be unesssesary in 2019. .NET was given the [ZipArchive class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8) back in Version 4.5. And .NET core - comming way after that - had it since 1.0. If you somehow lack it, something is really odd in your scenario. So you do not need commandline tools for the Unzipping part anyway.

The part of providing files for download is usually done by storing them [in/with a DB](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/). And then use a HTTP Handler to hand their data out when requested. So again, you can avoid any need for write rights (or at least keep writing contained to the DB Server).

Comment: The .bat file is not used to unzip the uploaded .zip file. It will scan the uploaded file and will generate scan results as xml and html files. I am using the DB as you stated but still need the results of .bat file

Comment: @Marwa Why do you need the results of the .bat file? What information does it provide that you can not also extract via ASP.Net code while it is in memory?

Comment: The .bat file is an utility that identifies uploaded project dependencies and checks if there are any known, publicly disclosed, vulnerabilities. Then will generate the results in a html or xml file.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try doing it in windows Shell script run as Administrator rather than .bat file?

Comment: Your "answer" here would be better as comment added to the original question.  Your "answer" amounts to a one-sentence question.